# how does if statement in xpath works?

Tags: xml, xpath-2.0

If we have an xpath if statement:

```
  if(test-expression) then (expresion) else (someOtherExpression),
```

and we say that test-expression is a path with some condition (for example //Element1[text() != ''])
and we have multiple Element1 nodes, does if statement goes into each Element1 node and checks condition or only the first?

example:

```
<Element1></Element1>
<Element1>Test</Element1>
```

If statement:

```
 if(//Element1[text()!='']) then ('result1') else ('result2')
```

will this return result2 for first element, and then go check second element and return1 or this is not how xpath works?

I am really new to xpath, and I cant find that information anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will this return result2 for first element, and then go check second element and return1 or this is not how xpath works?

No, it will evaluate the test expression, convert it to boolean, and then if the test was true it will return `result1` and if false it will return `result2`.

For this specific example

```
//Element1[text()!='']
```

is an expression that will return a sequence of all those `Element1` nodes that have at least one text node child that is not empty - it would find `<Element1>Test</Element1>` and `<Element1>Te<br/>st</Element1>`, but *not* `<Element1><span>Test</span></Element1>` because that `Element1` does not have any text node children at all, only an element node (the `span`).  If you want to catch that last example as well then you could use `. != ''` instead of `text() != ''`.

[The rule to convert a sequence of nodes to boolean](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-ebv) is that an empty sequence is false and a non-empty sequence is true.  Therefore the overall expression

```
if(//Element1[text()!='']) then ('result1') else ('result2')
```

will return `result1` if there is at least one `Element1` element in the document that has a non-empty text node child, and `result2` otherwise.

---

If you want to test each `Element1` in turn and return a *sequence* of `result1`/`result2` for each node, then you need a `for` expression

```
for $elt in (//Element1) return (if ($elt != '') then 'result1' else 'result2')
```

Comment: Maybe do you know how could I evaluate this for loop in C#?